# CollectionView should adjust scroll postion with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using a collection to delete a item I am just deleting an item from datasource and then reloading the CollectionView. on deleting the cell collection adjust its scroll position. This is happening without animation. I want the CollectionView to adjust scroll position with animation. How to do that ?

Comment: Don't reload the collection view. Call `deleteItems(at:)`

Comment: How you delete your cell ? could you share your code in the deleted? No need to reload you collection view after deleted

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, atScrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet may help you

**Get your current indexPath and delete row from below code may solve your problem**

```
yourCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])
```

**Note** : No need to reload your `CollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

you try that code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
self.images.removeObject(at: indexPath.item)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```